# Field extension generated by the roots of multivariate-polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-theory

Let us consider a field $K$ of characteristic $0$. Then we know that any finite extension $L$ of $K$, which is a Galois extension as well, is produced the roots of a separable polynomial $f(x) \in K[x]$. This we call the Galois theory for one variable polynomial.

How to construct a field extension $L$ of $K$ by the roots of a multivariable polynomial $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in K[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$ ? When $L$ would be Galois extension ?

The following is more elaborated question.

Consider a system polynomials \begin{align} f(x,y)=0\\g(x,y)=0 \end{align} . Let us define the set of solutions by $$S=\{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) \in L^2: ~f_1(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=0=f_2(\alpha_1,\alpha) \},$$ $\text{where $L$ is the required extension of $K$}$

From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604357/roots-of-multi-variable-polynomials-and-extension-fields), I know that the set $S$ of solution can be algebraic and thus $L$ might be a Galois extension of $K$, as well. However I am confused about the matter that ''the elements of $K$ are just scalars i.e., $1$-tuple while the elements in $S$ are like coordinates or $2$-tuple vector. So how does the solutions $f_1(x_1,x_2)=f_2(x_1,x_2)=0$ generate an algebraic extension of $K$ ?

Let me describe my question by giving an example-

Suppose I consider the following system of solutions \begin{align}f(x,y)&=x^2+y^2-2=0\\g(x,y)&=x^2-2y^2-1=0\end{align}

Then there are $4$ solutions $(\pm \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ over some extension $L$ of $K$, where we know what $L$ is.

**My question:** How do we describe the field extension in such cases?

Is the extension $L$ denoted by $K(\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}},-\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}, \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}},-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}) \cong K(\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}})$ ?

or is $L$ denoted by $K\left((\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}, \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}), (-\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}), (\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}},-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}), (-\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}},-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}})\right)$ ?

Clearly the first case is degree-one extension.

Any discussion please

**Note:** I have asked this same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4199173/425481) in math.stackexchange.com. From there I came to know that "coordinates $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ of a point $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ in a affine space generate the field extension".

Comment: Can the roots of some 2-variable polynomial $f(x_1,x_2) \in K[x_1,x_2]$ generate a Galois extension of $K$? It is possible, but you need to specify how you want to construct it. E.g. you can take the field $K'$ generated over $K$ by ALL $\beta$ such that $\beta = \alpha_1$ or $\beta = \alpha_2$ for some $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \in S$. $K'$ is a subfield of $L$, and therefore algebraic. You can try to study under what conditions $K'$ would be Galois - but is this what you want?

Comment: @auniket, Thanks. Yes i want to know when $K'$ is Galois generated by the coordinates of solutions in the affine space as you mentioned. Does usual separability conditions of the roots require to be Galois here ? However I am confused with your comment $\text{you need to specify how you want to construct it}$. Are there other ways to construct galois extension looking at my last example ?

Comment: Please give reason if downvoted so that i can develop the question.

Comment: Every finite separable extension is simple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem and it is easy to find a primitive element. That reduces the question to the usual Galois theory. Your example is a zero-dimensional subscheme of the affine plane. So you want to learn about its field of definition in algebraic geometry (with non-algebraically closed base field). Your example is uninteresting as $K(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})/K$ and its subextensions are all Galois. This question belongs to math.stackexchange where you asked it first.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich, Thanks for your help. So the upshot is that given a set of polynomials in $n$-variable over the field $K$, the solutions will not generate an extension $L$,say, but its `coordinates` will indeed generate the field extension. That is, in an affine space over the field $K$, the `coordinates` of each point generate the field extension. Is that all ?

Comment: It's common to use somewhat loose language, and to say "the field extension generated by the solutions" when one means "the field extension generated by the coordinates of the solutions". However, one always means "the field extension generated by the coordinates of the solutions" (as was already said in the comments of your math stack exchange question). Also, not directly answering your main question, but you seem to have miscalculated what this field actually is the line after "My question:". Math stack exchange would be a good place to ask for more details about that.

Comment: @WillSawin, Thanks. Can you help little more? It is clear to me that the `coordinates of solutions` of multivariable polynomials generate the field extension. The question is- When will such extension be Galois? For example, in my example the common solutions of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2=0$ and $g(x,y)=x^2-2y^2-1=0$ generate the Galois extension $K(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$ of $K$ with order of the Galois group $2$. What is the general criteria to check if the extension is Galois ? Suppose $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ has $m$-solutions over some extension $L$. How to check whether Galois or not ?

Comment: If you put in all coordinates of all solutions, it will always be Galois, since every Galois conjugate of a solution will be a solution.

Comment: @WillSawin, hi, I have another question. suppose $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n) \in K[x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n]$ has $m$-solutions over some extension $L$. Here $L$ is generated by the `coordinates` of those $m$-solutions and $L$ is Galois extension as you said in your previous comment. Thats ok. My question-what is the criteria to check whether the extension is Totally ramified or not ? Is there any Theorem to check this ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know a good one off the top of my head.

Comment: @WillSawin, ok, thanks